# convers typeorm to prisma ion nestjs error with mappers

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, prisma

Problem Statement:
You're working on a NestJS application developed with TypeORM.
You've been using mappers to map application models to database models.
In TypeORM, you could create an instance from your entity and map on arrays.
However, you're finding it challenging to perform similar operations in Prisma because Prisma doesn't have an array field to map on.
You're also using Prisma types like Prisma.CreateUserInput, but you're still unable to work with arrays effectively.

Comment: What's with all the "you're" stuff? Are you expecting us to do your homework?

Comment: What exactly is the question? What have you implemented with TypeORM that you are struggling to accomplish with Prisma?